# creating instance of contract trough a factory contract! Problems with balance!

Tags: solidity, ether, dapp-development, dapps, address.transfer

hopefully someone can help me with my question.

I have a factory to create an instance of a dealContract. Everything works except one thing. I cant send wei to the created instance, so lets see the code

```
 contract DealFactory {
    address[] public deployedDeals;


    function createDeal() public payable  {
        address newDeal = new Deal(msg.sender);

        deployedDeals.push(newDeal);

    }

    function getDeals() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedDeals;
    } 
}
```

The constructor of my Deal looks like this

```
 function Deal ( address _buyer) public payable {
      buyer
```

All i wanna do is, get the msg.value from the factory function to my Deal Contract.

Thanks in advance, I really have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
address newDeal = new Deal(msg.sender);
newDeal.transfer(msg.value);
```

or you can also do:

```
address newDeal = (new Deal).value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
```